# max scale in middle instead of end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following snippet, I am trying to achieve an effect where the `div` which appears in the middle of the visible scroll section is at full scale `scale(1);` and the other div's scale falloff towards `scale(0);` as they approach the edges.

I have drawn a debug box in the middle where the full scale div should appear.

```js
var viewport = {
  x: $("#scroll").scrollLeft(),
  width: $("#scroll").width(),
}

$("#scroll").scroll(function() {
  viewport.x = $("#scroll").scrollLeft();
  recalculateScale();
});

recalculateScale();

function recalculateScale() {
  $("#example > div").each(function() {
    let middleOfThis = ($(this).position().left + ($(this).width() * 0.5)); // calculate from the middle of each div
    let scale = Math.sin(middleOfThis / $("content").width());

    $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')');
  });
}
```

```css
content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

content::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#scroll {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#example {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: none;
}

#example>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<content>
  <div id="scroll">
    <section id="example">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</content>
```

Currently the scale is spanning from far left to right of `#example`. I know I need to factor the viewport dimensions into the equation before `Math.sin` is evaluated, I just can't get it quite right.

---

**Note:** no arrow functions because I have to target IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

- While `.position().left` returns the rendered position of the element *after* scaling, `.width()` returns the element's width *without* taking the scaling into account. Obviously such different way of measurement will lead to a wrong calculation of the middle point. Use `.getBoundingClientRect().width` instead: that will take the current scaling into account
- When using trigonometric functions, you need to make sure the argument represents an angle expressed in radians. In your code, the value ranges from 0 to 1, while the sine takes its maximum value not at 0.5, but at π/2. So you should perform a multiplication with π to get the desired result.

Here is the adapted code:

```js
var viewport = {
  x: $("#scroll").scrollLeft(),
  width: $("#scroll").width(),
}

$("#scroll").scroll(function() {
  viewport.x = $("#scroll").scrollLeft();
  recalculateScale();
});

recalculateScale();

function recalculateScale() {
  $("#example > div").each(function() {
    // 1. Use different way to read the width: this will give the rendered width 
    // after scaling, just like the left position will be the actually rendered 
    // position after scaling:
    let middleOfThis = $(this).position().left 
                     + this.getBoundingClientRect().width * 0.5; 
    // 2. Convert fraction to a number of radians:
    let scale = Math.sin(middleOfThis / $("content").width() * Math.PI);

    $(this).css('transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')');
  });
}
```

```css
content {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}

content::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#scroll {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#example {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: none;
}

#example>div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<content>
  <div id="scroll">
    <section id="example">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</content>
```

NB: Because of floating point precision limitations, the calculation of the mid points could slide away with little fractions. This will be so tiny, that it should not make a difference in actual pixel distance, but it would not hurt to pre-calculate the centres of the elements, so that you always use the same value.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent post. I knew that I was close, but I had no idea about the `.width()` caveat so that was interesting - cheers.